# How do I use argc, *argv[] to compute in C?

Tags: c

I'm calculating the volume of a sphere with a r-meter radius using argc and *argv[], I'm thinking if I enter "./radius 2" on the command line, argv[1] would become "2", so that the code would be:

```
        int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        float v;

        v = 4.0 / 3.0 * 3.14 * argv[1] * argv[1] * argv[1];
        printf("V = %f\n", v);
        return 0;
        }
```

but it seems that argv can't do the calculation.
What should I do?

Comment: Start from understanding that `argv[i]` is a *string*

Comment: Use `atoi` to convert "2" to an `int` or `atof` to convert it to a `double`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `argv` isn't doing any computation, it's just data. Rather, you're doing some computation that _uses_ `argv`.

Comment: As posted, `argv[i]` should be telling you that `i` is undefined. If you wanted `argv[1]` you should make sure `1` is not greater than (or equal to) `argc`.

Answer (score 3):

Command line arguments are passed to the program as *strings* - you'll need to use `atof` or `strtod` to convert the string representation of a value to its numeric equivalent.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  // All kinds of error checking ommitted
  double input = strtod( argv[1], NULL );
  double v = 4.0 / 3.0 * 3.14 * input * input * input;
  ...
}
```

Unless you're really constrained on space, use `double` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a variable `i`. You can think of `argv` as a string array if you want, `argv[0]` is the name of your executable so in this case `./radius`,  `argv[1]` in your case will be 2 and so on.

One thing you should keep in mind is that it's good practice to check `argc` to ensure you have the parameters you want, `argc` will tell you the length of `argv` so in your case it will be 2.

you can then use the number you passed like:

```
double arg = atof(argv[1]);
double v = 4.0 / 3.0 * 3.14 * arg * arg * arg;
```

or:

```
int i = 1;
double arg = atof(argv[i]);
double v = 4.0 / 3.0 * 3.14 * arg * arg * arg;
```

or again (the worst method):

```
double v = 4.0 / 3.0 * 3.14 * atof(argv[1]) * atof(argv[1]) * atof(argv[1]);
```

If for some reason you **REALLY** don't want to have separate variables

but like i said, you should first check that you have enough arguments with `argc` and that the argument is what you actually want (E.G. a number and not a string)